# pod shows existing but get pod not found error when running port-forward

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

when I run `kubectl get pods` it shows pod existing and ready, but when run `kubectl port-forward` I get `pod not foud` error. what's going on here?

```
(base):~ zwang$ k get pods -n delivery
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf   1/1     Running   86         7h18m
(base):~ zwang$ k port-forward screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf 8000:8000
Error from server (NotFound): pods "screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf" not found
```

Comment: You need to provide the `-n delivery` option to specify the namespace in both commands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace on the `port-forward` command too. `kubectl port-forward -n delivery screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf 8000:8000`

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands

```
k config set-context --current --namespace=delivery
k port-forward screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf 8000:8000 &

OR

k -n delivery port-forward screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf 8000:8000 &
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the namespace while accessing the Pod.

```
 kubectl port-forward screenshot-history-7f76489574-wntkf 8000:8000 -n delivery
```

Another option is change the current namespace to your desired one. Then you can directly work without passing any namespace. You can see more info to change the current namespace from this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration).